# No architectures in the binary. Lipo is failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable

Tags: ios, xcode

Yes i know there is other answers to this question and I looked at all of them and for some darn reason I keep getting this error no matter what i try. I have tried all the solutions that have been suggested and before i mess things up really bad, i thought it best to come here and just post the question.

Please help me
I am using Xcode ver 5.1.1 and these are my screen shots of what my plist looks like and the build settings are in the target but i can't post them because my reputation is too low. UGH!

Comment: Edit your question to show the `lipo` command line you are using and also show the output from `lipo -info /path/to/binary`.

Comment: where would i find the lipo command line?

Comment: In the build log - select the detail drop down on the right of the line.

Comment: i am assuming you mean in the build locations in Targets? the build products path is just build, pre-configuration build products path is build/Debug-iphoneos and build/Release-iphoneos

Comment: No, the build log: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-log_navigator/articles/log_navigator-about.html

Comment: I can't find a line that has anything that says lipo on it when i look at the build log for the archiving

Comment: So where did you get "lipo" from then in your question?

Comment: Thats what i get when i try to validate my app, I have no idea what that means or why i am getting the error

Comment: OK, are you able to find the executable on your development machine file system (it's in `DerivedData`, which is probably in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode`, if I remember right).

Comment: NO all i find in that folder is a folder called templates. I am on Mavericks

Comment: Found them in a similar folder

Comment: OK, so run `lipo -info` on the file and post the results.

Comment: i keep getting invalid argument when i try to fun this in the command line. I am typing lipo -info /path/to/.app file there is no .app file in the Release-iphoneos folder

Comment: The .app path is not a correct target for lipo, you need a path to the executable file as an argument, e.g. `~/MyApp/build/MyApp.app/MyAppTarget`. Also feel free to upload your images to any host, edit the question and add the links (please don't post them as a comment).

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a new project and copying all the files to the new project. I just gave up on trying to figure out what i did wrong. I opened the project in the Xcode 6 beta to see if it was still compatible, though I am not sure thats what made things go haywire, its the only thing that i can think of that may have made a mess with the architectures. Thanks for all your help and patience though.